# How to call every attribute of a class to its inherited class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Base:
   def __init__(self, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, ...):
       self.t1 = t1
       self.t2 = t2
       self.t3 = t3
       self.t4 = t4
       self.t5 = t5
       ...

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, base_obj):
        super(Derived, self).__init__(t1 = base_obj.t1, t2 = base_obj.t2, t3 = base_obj.t3, ...)
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3

base_obj1 = Base(1,2,3,4,5,...)
derived_obj1 = Derived('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', base_obj1)
```

As you can see `Base` has a lots of attributes and I inherit them in the `Derived` one-by-one which is very difficult to do, is there a way like I can just do **something like this**

```
super(Derived, self).__init__(self = base_obj)
```

So I don't have to inherit every attribute of `Base` in `Derived` manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that the `Base` class have a method which picks the right attributes for you:

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, ...):
       self.t1 = t1
       self.t2 = t2
       self.t3 = t3
       self.t4 = t4
       self.t5 = t5
       ...

    #Base should know which attributes are created in __init__()
    #so this method just has to be kept in sync
    def pick_init_attributes(self):
        return (self.t1, self.t2, self.t3, ...)

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, base_obj):
        super().__init__(*base_obj.pick_init_attributes())
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3

base_obj1 = Base(1,2,3,4,5,...)
derived_obj1 = Derived('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', base_obj1)
```

Also, when it comes time to write: `class Derived2(Base):` you only need to copy/paste the `super()...` line without needing to check whether it has the right attributes.

Comment: hmm I guess, I can try that